# Calling @property accessor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wonder if someone can explain the following, are these both doing the same? As both call "setSeparatorColor" I would guess they are both calling the accessor for the property.

```
[myTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

.

```
[[self myTableView] setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Gary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct, they are both doing the same

```
[myTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Is accessing the variable directly, where as

```
[[self myTableView] setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Is calling the accessor for the property, and then sending the `setSeparatorColor` message to it

Comment: No, they are not the same.  The first one accesses the instance variable directly.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the same.

In the first version you use instance variable of some class - `myTableView`.

In the second version you use value, returned by same-named method. On the first step current class's method `- (..)myTableView;` is called This method returns some value. And on the next step - you use `- (..)setSeparatorColor:..` method of returned object. Of course, often (when you use `@synthesize myTableView;` or method implementation like `- (..)myTableView { return myTableView; }`) it is the same variable as in the first version, but it isn't mandatory condition (depends on your implementation). Moreover, `- (..)myTableView;` can have some side effects / do additional work - not just returning a value.

An example (myTableView and [self myTableView] can be different, depending on some condition):

```
// myClass.h
@interface myClass : UIViewController {
    UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;
@end;

// myClass.m
#import "myClass.h"

@implementation myClass

@dynamic myTableView;

- (UITableView *)myTableView {
    return (someConditionIsTrue) ? myTableView : nil;
}

- (void)setMyTableView:(UITableView *)value {
    if (myTableView != value) {
        [myTableView release];
        myTableView = [value retain];
    }
}

@end;
```